# Considering column instead of strings

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to apply the following code to this column:

```
Test
"Find the number behind the lines"
"Look at the sky"
"It is a such wonderful day today"
```

In the following code, docs are a list of documents; in my case they should be the rows in Test column.

```
D = np.zeros((len(docs), len(docs)))
for i in range(len(docs)):
    for j in range(len(docs)):
        if i == j:
            continue  
        if i > j:
            D[i, j] = D[j, i]
```

How can I apply it to my column?

In my code, I am assuming your list of strings/rows (each a list-of-words) is docs, to calculate the array of pairwise distances D with the code above. The problem is in applying it to a column.

The expected output (but I cannot determine with the code above, unfortunately) would be the similarity of reference sentence and other sentences. i,j are my indices and they run through each row in the column Test. The algorithm I am going to use is the mover's distance.

Comment: Can you explain the expected behaviour of your code, and share expected output please

Comment: Put your code into a function and use df.Test.apply(lambda x: function(x))

Comment: I updated the question providing some context about the behaviour of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def f(docs):

D = np.zeros((len(docs), len(docs)))
for i in range(len(docs)):
    for j in range(len(docs)):
        if i == j:
            continue  
        if i > j:
            D[i, j] = D[j, i] 




df.Test.apply(lambda x: f(x))
```

Comment: A little explanation would improve this answer

Answer (score 0):

from your question i understood u want ro rename your row and column with strings of docs. if that's right try this

```
docs=["Find the number behind the lines","Look at the sky","It is a such wonderful day today"]

D = np.zeros((len(docs), len(docs)))
df=pd.DataFrame(D,columns=docs,index=docs)
print(df)
```

Comment: if u dont want to be a dataframe you can convert back to numpy array

Comment: Hi @M.LakshmiNarayanan LAK. Unfortunately I am looking for something slightly different. Right now docs should be documents (so like strings); however I have tried to used and apply the code to the strings within a column in pandas. But it seems that this is not the right way to prceed

Comment: @LucaDiMauro can you post what is the output you are expecting as a sample